# python group multiple similar if statement

Tags: python

How to group a large amount of similar if else statement or is writing like the following good practice?

```
if len(G72List) > 1 and G72List[1] != "":
    G7201Value = G72List[1]
else:
    G7201Value = ""

if len(G72List) > 5 and G72List[5] != "":
    G7205Value = G72List[5]
else:
    G7205Value = ""

if len(G72List) > 6 and G72List[6] != "":
    G7206Value = G72List[6]
else:
    G7206Value = ""

if len(G72List) > 7 and G72List[7] != "":
    G7207Value = G72List[7]
else:
    G7207Value = ""

if len(G72List) > 8 and G72List[8] != "":
    G7208Value = G72List[8]
else:
    G7208Value = ""

if len(G72List) > 9 and G72List[9] != "":
    G7209Value = G72List[9]
else:
    G7209Value = ""

if len(G72List) > 10 and G72List[10] != "":
    G7210Value = G72List[10]
else:
    G7210Value = ""
```

Comment: You should be able to refactor code that repetitive into a for loop.

Comment: A rule of thumb: if your variables are starting to get numbers in their names, you should consider using a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A series of variable names that differ only by number can be refactored into a dict (or possibly a list if you're starting at 0 and incrementing by 1). Then the repetition can be factored out into a for loop.

```
GValue = {}
for i in [1, *range(5, 11)]:
    if len(G72List) > i and G72List[i] != "":
        GValue[7200+i] = G72List[i]
    else:
        GValue[7200+i] = ""
```

Comment: I forgot to add there is a 1 and then it skips to 5 (see edit).  Anyway to incorporate into the loop without extra if else?

Comment: @bakalolo for small ranges you can just unpack the range into a list with the extra items. If the range is big enough that it would take too much memory, then you can use itertools.chain to concatenate iterables into a single iterator instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this way to demo what you could do:

```
from contextlib import suppress


G7201Value = G7205Value = G7206Value = G7207Value = G7209Value = G7210Value = 'empty'


for i in range(12):
    G72List = [_ for _ in range(i)]
    print(G72List)
    
    with suppress(IndexError):
        G7201Value = G72List[1]
        G7205Value = G72List[5]
        G7206Value = G72List[6]
        G7207Value = G72List[7]
        G7208Value = G72List[8]
        G7209Value = G72List[9]
        G7210Value = G72List[10]


    print(
        G7201Value,
        G7205Value,
        G7206Value,
        G7207Value,
        G7209Value,
        G7210Value
     )
```

Output:

```
$ python3 g27.py 
[]
empty empty empty empty empty empty
[0]
empty empty empty empty empty empty
[0, 1]
1 empty empty empty empty empty
[0, 1, 2]
1 empty empty empty empty empty
[0, 1, 2, 3]
1 empty empty empty empty empty
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
1 empty empty empty empty empty
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1 5 empty empty empty empty
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
1 5 6 empty empty empty
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
1 5 6 7 empty empty
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
1 5 6 7 empty empty
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
1 5 6 7 9 empty
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
1 5 6 7 9 10
```

Simple but efficient ;-)

Let me explain:

You where trying to see if the list was long enough, then checking if the value at the index you where looking to extract from had a value, then assign it, or set the value to `""`. you do not need to do this, you can just initialise the variables all at once with an empty string.
After, using `contextlib.suppress(IndexError)`, allows the section of code indented after `suppress` to proceed as long as `IndexError` is not raised ;-)

Disclaimer:

```
for i in range(12):
    G72List = [_ for _ in range(i)]
    print(G72List)
```

was just for the purpose of the demo, to show you the behaviour with a list of various lenght.